# How to create a loop that returns the first N prime numbers in a vector?

Tags: r, function, loops

i've been trying for a while now to write a function that has two arguments. The one an integer = n and the other a logical argument. How would i write a function that would return either the first n prime numbers in a vector if the logical argument is true or the n th prime number if the logical argument is false?

This is as far as i have gotten.

```
getprime <- function(n=0 , all=TRUE) {
    if (n<=0) {
    print("Not a valid number") 

    } else if (n>0) {
        for (primen in 1:n) {
         while (n %% 2:(n-1) == 0) {
        n=n+1
        print(n)
    }   
    }
    }
    print(n)
}
```

The results that have to be displayed are shown below.

```
> genprime(7, all=TRUE)
[1] 2 3 5 7 11 13 17
> genprime(7, all=FALSE)
[1] 17
```

Comment: Hi , i did forget to add the a function to check for primeness but that isn't where i'm stuck. I just cant seem to create a loop that returns a vector of the first n'th prime numbers. The task also needs to be one function that doesn't use any added packages in R.

Comment: The whole task has to be done in one function , so i cannot write a seperate function and include it in the new function. I already wrote a function to check for primes but i cant use it as everything needs to be done in one function.

Comment: Deleted my comments because the advice was a bit off. Have you thought about the algorithm? How do you want this to work? Let's say `n = 3`. What should it do? You need to check if 1 is prime? no. Check if 2 is prime? Yes! -- add 2 to a `primes_vector`. How long is the primes vector? only one number in it, 2, but we need n = 3 primes. Better keep going. Check if 3 is prime? Yes! ... etc. The main question is how you want to check for prime-ness, what numbers you need to check if they divide your current prime candidate.

Comment: I want to say that *"The whole task has to be done in one function , so i cannot write a seperate function and include it in the new function"* is a really dumb requirement. Good programming is writing lots of little functions and putting them together. You could include your `is_prime` function definition *inside* this function and still use it.

Comment: What you described is exactly what i want to do! But im confused on how to repeat the loop until N primes is reached.  I used `any(n %% 2:(n-1) == 0)` to check if a number is prime or not but to continue this check and add the primes into a vector is where i am stuck.

Comment: Also i have to agree, the requirement is quite dumb. Our lecturer insisted that it is written as one function though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a recursive function (a function that calls itself). In addition to the two arguments `n` and `all`, it would also take a counter `i` and a (empty) vector of prime numbers `primes`.

As long as the number of prime numbers found is less than `n`, the function calls itself and with each time it calls itself, it would increase the counter variable `i`. If `i` is a prime number, it gets added to the `primes` vector.

```
get_prime <- function(n, all = TRUE, i = 1, primes = c()){
  if ( n <= 0) {
    stop("Not a valid number")
  }

  if (length(primes) < n) {
    if (i == 2L || all(i %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(i)) != 0)) {
      get_prime(n, all = all, i = i + 1, primes = c(primes, i))
    } else {
      get_prime(n, all = all, i = i + 1, primes = primes)
    }
  } else {
    if (all) {
      return(primes)
    } else {
      return(tail(primes, 1))
    }
  }
}
```

The results are:

```
get_prime(7, TRUE)
[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17
get_prime(7, FALSE)
[1] 17
```

Comment: And, if you want to be fancy, instead of checking `2L:ceiling(sqrt(i))`, check `primes[primes <= ceiling(sqrt(i))]`.  (would work better if you hard-code `2` as the first prime so `primes` is never empty)

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance. Our lecturer threw us into the deep end on this as we have barely done any R work in our statistics course so ive been struggling quite a bit. Also why did you use `i == 2L` what does the 2L mean and why did you use `ceiling(sqrt(i)`?

Comment: Would it be possible also to only use 2 arguments in the function as opposed to 4?